# Why the pods returns Error or ExitCode:0 even they run successfully?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nfs

There's two kinds of status code of one-shot pods, running from API or the command:

`kubectl run --restart=Never --image test:v0.1 ...`.

The pods produce output files to a NFS server, and I've got files successfully.

`kubectl get pods -ao wide`:

```
NAME       READY     STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE       
test-90    0/1       ExitCode:0   0          23m       192.168.1.43
test-91    0/1       ExitCode:0   0          23m       192.168.1.43
test-92    0/1       ExitCode:0   0          23m       192.168.1.43
test-93    0/1       ExitCode:0   0          23m       192.168.1.43
test-94    0/1       Error        0          23m       192.168.1.46
test-95    0/1       Error        0          23m       192.168.1.46
test-96    0/1       Error        0          23m       192.168.1.46
test-97    0/1       Error        0          23m       192.168.1.46
test-98    0/1       Error        0          23m       192.168.1.46
test-99    0/1       ExitCode:0   0          23m       192.168.1.43
```

the description of `ExitCode:0` pod:

```
Name:                           test-99
Namespace:                      default
Image(s):                       test:v0.1
Node:                           192.168.1.43/192.168.1.43
Status:                         Succeeded
Replication Controllers:        <none>
Containers:
  test:
    State:              Terminated
      Exit Code:        0
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
```

the description of `Error` pod:

```
Name:                           test-98
Namespace:                      default
Image(s):                       test:v0.1
Node:                           192.168.1.46/192.168.1.46
Status:                         Succeeded
Replication Controllers:        <none>
Containers:
  test:
    State:              Terminated
      Reason:           Error
      Exit Code:        0
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      0
```

Their NFS volumes:

```
Volumes:
  input:
    Type:       NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
    Server:     192.168.1.46
    Path:       /srv/nfs4/input
    ReadOnly:   false
  output:
    Type:       NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
    Server:     192.168.1.46
    Path:       /srv/nfs4/output
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-nmviv:
    Type:       Secret (a secret that should populate this volume)
    SecretName: default-token-nmviv
```

`kubectl logs` returns none, since the container just produces output files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of kubernetes do you use? `kubectl version`

Comment: @Yu-JuHong  Kubernetes 1.1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, any commands passed into the pods returns Error status.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue with  Kubernetes v1.1.4, have you find the reason yet? I am actually just following the simple hello-world example with restartPolicy set to Never.

Comment: @zyxue Not yet. One of the reasonable explanations is [quickly existing](http://serverfault.com/a/734015). But if `ExitCode 0` is normal, what about the `Error`? I've tried to run docker on local machine, debug within the docker, and all of them work fine. XD

Answer (score 4):

`ExitCode 0` means it terminated normally

Exit codes can be used if you pipe to another process, so the process knows what to do next (if previous process failed do this, else do something with the data passed...)

Comment: Thanks! I've test the scripts in container, the exit code is exactly `0`, but why some of the pods terminated with `Error`?

Comment: well i think the replication controller says succeeded if it succeeded in launching the pod per the request, which in tour case is a one time process so it will always succeed as long as the image is available to run. now why the pod may exit with an error depends on what you actually run. it is possible that it could not mount the nfs store and failed. you would need to output something in the image to check and get useful logs of what is happening

Comment: Thank you! I've checked the output files in nfs server moments ago, and the files are stored as expected. This problem is really wired.